# error while connecting sqlite database file using node js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am new to Node.Js and have written the below code to connect to the SQLite db file. But unfortunately getting error-ed out. please help

Node - 4.6.0:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db =new sqlite3.Database('./db/program', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE,(err)                             
if (err) { console.error(err.message);  }
console.log('Connected to the database.');});
```

Error message:

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/program', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Node 4.6.0 it doesn't support ES6 syntax out of the box. You need to use the `strict` mode and write code.`let` is supported out of the box after Node v6.0.0.

So, maybe you can upgrade Node.JS or you can just add,

```
"use strict";
```

in the  1st line of the code. It should work.

Check ES6 compatibility here: https://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-let
Learn more about Strict mode: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp